# Convert String.Index to Int or Range<String.Index> to NSRange

Tags: string, swift

So I've found issues relating to the case of converting `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>`, but I've actually run into the opposite problem.

Quite simply, I have a `String` and a `Range<String.Index>` and need to convert the latter into an `NSRange` for use with an older function.

So far my only workaround has been to grab a substring instead like so:

```
func foo(theString: String, inRange: Range<String.Index>?) -> Bool {
    let theSubString = (nil == inRange) ? theString : theString.substringWithRange(inRange!)
    return olderFunction(theSubString, NSMakeRange(0, countElements(theSubString)))
}
```

This works of course, but it isn't very pretty, I'd much rather avoid having to grab a sub-string and just use the range itself somehow, is this possible?

Comment: Where do you want to use the range instead of the substring? As argument to olderFunction? Then what is it's purpose?

Comment: I suppose my example may be confusing the issue since it only returns a `Bool`, however, some other similar functions return more complex results, which are going to require correction when using this sub-string trick, since the indices they return will be for `theSubString` rather than `theString`.

Is there really no way to just convert `String.Index` to an `Int`?

Comment: something that worked for me (in my situation): `if idx.startIndex == url.startIndex { // some code }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look into the definition of `String.Index` you find:

```
struct Index : BidirectionalIndexType, Comparable, Reflectable {

    /// Returns the next consecutive value after `self`.
    ///
    /// Requires: the next value is representable.
    func successor() -> String.Index

    /// Returns the previous consecutive value before `self`.
    ///
    /// Requires: the previous value is representable.
    func predecessor() -> String.Index

    /// Returns a mirror that reflects `self`.
    func getMirror() -> MirrorType
}
```

So actually there is no way to convert it to `Int` and that for good reason. Depending on the encoding of the string the single characters occupy a different number of bytes. The only way would be to count how many `successor` operations are needed to reach the desired `String.Index`.

**Edit** The definition of `String` has changed over the various Swift versions but it's basically the same answer. To see the very current definition just CMD-click on a `String` definition in XCode to get to the root (works for other types as well).

The `distanceTo` is an extension which goes to a variety of protocols. Just look for it in the `String` source after the CMD-click.

Comment: I understand the reasons for it, but it's unfortunate. It wouldn't be so bad if I could at least determine that two String.Index values represented a difference of say, 5 characters, as I could use advance(5) to trivially correct my results as it's making working with older code very tricky =(

Comment: You might abbreviate that with an extension. Character strings are in fact voodoo or black magic. We never should have left the 7-bit ASCII tree ;-)

Comment: Perhaps not, though actually I've just discovered the `distance()` function (or preprocessor, I'm not sure); anyway, it allows for determining the difference between two `String.Index`'s like so: `distance(theString.startIndex, theRange.startIndex)`. It's still not pretty but I think I can make it work for now, I just hope it doesn't have to handle huge strings in future ;)

Comment: Luckily most strings are relatively short. However, I've seen implementations handling BLOB as string (which of course is not a good idea). See also here: http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/14/the-swift-standard-library-list-of-built-in-functions/ This lists all those predefined functions. Simply a design fault since you have to learn all of them - and I forgot about it :-(

Answer (score 8):

I don't know which version introduced it, but in Swift 4.2 you can easily convert between the two.

To convert `Range<String.Index>` to `NSRange`:

```
let range   = s[s.startIndex..<s.endIndex]
let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: s)
```

To convert `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>`:

```
let nsRange = NSMakeRange(0, 4)
let range   = Range(nsRange, in: s)
```

Keep in mind that `NSRange` is UTF-16 based, while `Range<String.Index>` is `Character` based. 
Hence you can't just use counts and positions to convert between the two!

Answer (score 7):

```
let index: Int = string.startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4, `distanceTo()` is deprecated. You may have to convert `String` to `NSString` to take advantage of its `-[NSString rangeOfString:]` method, which returns an `NSRange`.

Comment: Yeah, NSString has more amenities than typical String. I appreciate that answer!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 Complete Solution:

OffsetIndexableCollection (String using Int Index)

https://github.com/frogcjn/OffsetIndexableCollection-String-Int-Indexable-

```
let a = "01234"

print(a[0]) // 0
print(a[0...4]) // 01234
print(a[...]) // 01234

print(a[..<2]) // 01
print(a[...2]) // 012
print(a[2...]) // 234
print(a[2...3]) // 23
print(a[2...2]) // 2

if let number = a.index(of: "1") {
    print(number) // 1
    print(a[number...]) // 1234
}

if let number = a.index(where: { $0 > "1" }) {
    print(number) // 2
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function and call it when ever you need convertion

```
extension String
{ 
    func CnvIdxTooIntFnc(IdxPsgVal: Index) -> Int
    {
        return startIndex.distanceTo(IdxPsgVal)
    }
}
```